# How can I recover a game center account where I forgot ID and password?

Tags: apple-id, game-center

A long time ago, I made a game center account to which I attached my CoC village. This account hasn't been used anymore, and I have forgotten the ID and the password.

Now I want to transfer that game to my new phone which has a new game center ID, but need a transfer code from the old account to do so. Is there a way to recover my old game center account details?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options to recover your Game Center login:

- check whether Game Center (the app) is still logged in with the old account, then use this information to reset the password at https://iforgot.apple.com/
- go directly to https://appleid.apple.com and try to recover your account from there